# Python Selenium hover action concatenates in memory

Tags: python, selenium, memory, hover

I am testing a website which has a menu with submenus appearing on hover.

I have created a function to interact with this menu:

```
def go_to(navbar_item, menu_item):
    # find the navbar item
    assets_main_menu = driver.find_element(By.ID, navbar_item)
    #hover over the navbar item, so the submenu appears
    hover.move_to_element(assets_main_menu).perform()
    # find the submenu item
    xpath = "//*[contains(text(), \'" + menu_item + "\')]"
    destination = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    # hover over the submenu item and clicks
    hover.move_to_element(destination).click().perform()
```

The problem is that i use this function more than once such as:

```
# action 1
go_to('navbar item1 id', 'submenu item1')
do_something()
# action 2
go_to('navbar item1 id', 'submenu item2')
do something()
# action 3
go_to('navbar item1 id', 'submenu item3')
do_something()
```

selenium actually repeats the previous steps going through the past menu items like:

ACTUAL OUPTUP
action 1, do something -> action 1, action 2, do something -> action 1, action 2, action 3, do something

Instead my DESIRED OUTPUT would be:

action 1, do something -> action 2, do something -> action 3, do something

---

I tried unsetting the variables:

navbar_item, menu_item, hover, xpath, destination.

at the end of the function with no luck.

I have also tried to instantiate hover within my function

hover = ActionChains(driver);

but in this last attempt my code stopped working.

Comment: In you update you said your code stopped working. Can you clarify and share the same error?... In your original code you're reusing your actions chain - you need to clear that down between each use so you're on the right lines... You can also Try hover.reset_actions at the end

Comment: @RichEdwards, thanks for your reply. I amended my post I hope it seems less ambiguous now... What I meant is that only in the last case, when i instantiated hover within the function, the code stopped working, otherwise everything would work, just the execution has the actions concatenated

Comment: Error messages are there to be read :-) is the error that driver is null/undefined? - entirely depends on the structure of your code, but with what you have provided, your def doesn't know what driver is. Did you try hover.reset_actions()?

Comment: thank you @RichEdwards, your solution worked, i had to review my code, I was implementing the function in a different file and importing them, and instantiating the driver there, so putting driver in the function arguments was not working. 
Now I have had to add driver as argument to all my functions but at least this works.
PS. hover.rest_actions() did not work for me neither, however I could use "hover".
Unfortunately I cannot rate your solution because my rank is too low!

Thanks again this was really ruining my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call an action chain, `perform()` does not clear out the previous steps. You've only really shared your function so the real culprit is the structure of your code and how python consumes variables.

I note in your function, you pass in two `strings` but your function knows what `driver` and `hover` are. Which sounds like you're using global variables.

To demo your problem I created this simple page for you with a click counter:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="button" onclick="document.getElementById('input').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value) + 1">Click me</button>
        <input id="input" value="0"></input>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's a flat page that just knocks up a number each time you press the button:
[image: clicker]

Then, to show you what's happening, i created a similar version of your code:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(r"c:\git\test.html")

actions = ActionChains(driver)

def ClickByActions(element):
    actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

#find the button and click it a few times...
button = driver.find_element_by_id('button')
ClickByActions(button)
ClickByActions(button)
ClickByActions(button)
```

With this, you  expect the end click-count-value to be 3. However, it is 6.
[image]

Same as your problem. First call does +1, second call does +1 +1, third call does +1 +1 +1.

Finally! the solution - create action chain in the function with your driver:

```py
def ClickByActions(element):
    localActions = ActionChains(driver)
    localActions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

[image: end result]

I note in the comments you say you tried this. Can you please try:

- not using `hover` but another name -
- pass in driver instead of relying on it being a global variable. For this you would use `go_to(navbar_item, menu_item, driver)`
- Apparently `hover.reset_actions()` should also work - but this didn't work for me.

If these don't work, please share your site URL so I can try on your actual site or say what the error is and describe what happens.